# MomentJS, UTC timestamp, is it a issue or wrong?, few queries

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm not finding any difference in the timestamp when using `moment().valueOf()` and `moment.utc().valueOff()`, I have timezoneOffset with +5.

```
console.log(moment().valueOf())
console.log(moment().valueOf())
console.log(moment().utc().valueOf(),  moment().valueOf(), '=', moment().utc().valueOf() -  moment().valueOf())

> 1564388008550
> 1564388008551
> 1564388008551 1564388008551 "=" 0
```

Expected must be 5 hours difference? Or may be our perspective is wrong usually timestamp always be in UTC? that is why both the method provide same timestamp! and we can find the difference only in formatted date string?

Comment: timestamp doesn't know what a timezone is, so your timestamp will always be in UTC, then you need to add timezone over it if you need it

Comment: A timestamp is any representation of a date and/or time. In the OP, 1564388008550 is a timestamp only if you know it's a millisecond offset from 1970-01-01, otherwise it's just a number. ECMA-262 calls that number a time value. Timezones change the offset from UTC, so changing the timezone offset just changes the displayed date and time (timestamp), it doesn't change the time value. The *utc* method just sets the default to UTC (i.e. no timezone), so displayed timestamps change to UTC, but not the time value.

Comment: @jonatjano and RobG - thanks for confirming, that timstamp always be in UTC

Answer (score 1):

moment.js instances are wrappers for native Date objects, which use a time value that is always UTC. Different timezones may be used for **displaying** dates (timestamps), but the time value does not change.

By default, moment's output is local. The *utc* method sets a moment instance to UTC mode, so by default output is displayed as UTC. It does not change the UTC time value at the heart of the Date wrapped by the moment instance, e.g.

```js
let m = moment();

console.log('time value: ' + m.valueOf());  // time value of instance
console.log('local timestamp: ' + m.format()); // timestamp in host timezone

m.utc();  // set to UTC mode, so default is UTC

console.log('time value: ' + m.valueOf()); // time value unchanged
console.log('UTC timestamp: ' + m.format()); // Equivalent timestamp with no timezone (UTC)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```